# Java8 LocalDate changing ISO region to US

Tags: java

What I'm looking for is an integer representation of the day of the week with Sunday being the start of the week at 1.

My code:

```
String date = "2017-10-10";
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
System.out.println(dateTime.getDayOfWeek().getValue());
```

This is returning a 2 for Tuesday instead of a 3.  How do I change it to a Sunday week start instead of a Monday week start?

From the searching I've been doing I think this is based on my region but Im not sure.

Comment: `(dateTime.getDayOfWeek().getValue()+1)%7`?

Comment: You may just set the region instead.

Comment: This Numeric value is set in `Enum DayOfWeek` (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), Hence there is no way by jdk to change that value. You need re calculate the int if you need